# Help me understand the recovered file system

Tags: lvm, raid, mdadm, synology

So I had a Synology machine that went bottoms up (motherboard). I built a debian system myself and installed the hard disks today. After some twiddling with `mdadm` I was able to mount the both hard disks in the array setup. This is what it looks like now:

[image: lsblk output]

`sdb` and `sdc` are my hard disks running like an array.

So what I don't understand is that what is `btrfs`. I understand that it is a file system but does it run on top of `mdadm`? what is `mdadm` then? I read somewhere that `btrfs` can be configured in RAID levels? Does it mean that `btrfs` is using `mdadm` to setup arrays? I had to install `lvm2` package as well to get it working? how does that come into picture?

Comment: Please [don't post pictures of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text). It's really hard to read.

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR; In your setup, mdadm is used for RAID, then LVM is used to logically partition the available storage space, and then each partition is formatted with the btrfs file system.**

> So what I don't understand is that what is btrfs. I understand that it is a file system but does it run on top of mdadm?

Yes, the full name is [B-tree file system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Btrfs), and it is simply a file system, similar to [ext4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4), [vfat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table), etc.

> what is mdadm then?

Per the [manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mdadm.8.html),

> mdadm - manage MD devices aka Linux Software RAID

This is a software RAID implementation.

> I read somewhere that btrfs can be configured in RAID levels? Does it mean that btrfs is using mdadm to setup arrays?

Yes, and no. As a file system, btrfs itself implements [certain RAID configurations](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mkfs.btrfs.8.html#PROFILES).
However, mdadm is capable of setting up RAID on it's own.

> I had to install lvm2 package as well to get it working? how does that come into picture?

Per it's [manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/lvm.8.html),

> The Logical Volume Manager (LVM) provides tools to create virtual block devices from physical devices.

Comment: What role is LVM playing in this particular configuration? Isn't LVM kind of expansion tool on top of physical drives. What is mdadm doing in between?

Comment: LVM is used to logically partition the drives. I wouldn't say mdadm is in between, but rather underneath. Think of it as a RAID controller, it just happens to be software also.

Comment: so LVM is looking at disks as just md2 in my case? or Is md2 first formatted with btrfs and them LVM is made on top of those partitions? Btw both the disks have 3 partitions already on it from Synology. Those are partitioned as "Linux raid member".

what steps could one take to recreate such a setup from ground up?

Comment: So sdx1,2,5 are all partitions used by `mdadm`. The md2's are used by LVM. The vg1000-lv's are then formatted with btrfs.